# RoR devise: sign_in always returns invalid email/password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Every time I log in, I get the error msg that the email/password is invalid.

routes:

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  post '/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
end

resources :users
```

user model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :gender, :remember_me
```

view:

```
<% if signed_in?(:user) %>
   Hi <%= current_user.first_name %>. | Not you? <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to 'Sign up', signup_path %> or <%= link_to 'Sign in', user_session_path, :method => :create %>
<% end %>
```

I tried changing the routes to:

```
get '/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
```

and changing the respective paths, but that didn't change anything.

I even changed the code in the view from:

```
if signed_in?(:user)
```

to:

```
if user_signed_in?
```

and did a combination of these things and nothing is working.

I did ask devise to handle the confirmation as well, which I did by copying the generated link to the browser and it signs me in as the user the first time.  It also allows me to change the password via the email confirmation link, which also signs me in upon changing the password.  But once I sign out and sign back in, it tells me that the email/password is invalid again.

Can anyone help?

I am using rails 3.0.7, devise 1.4.5, capybara 1.1.1, cucumber 1.0.6, mysql2 0.2.6 and rake 0.8.7 if that helps anyone.

Thanks

EDIT:

To help future users, there is actually nothing wrong with the gem.  It works fine.  The issue is with my database.  For some reason, it is selecting a NULL email from the database instead of pulling the info of the user I am trying to log in.  I am figuring out how to fix this now and will update once I figure it out.

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been having a similar issue on a fresh install of Devise, but what I found is that if I ran `bundle update` then restarted my dev server it works.

At first I wasn't seeing the DB query in the `development.log`, but once I updated my `Gemfile` (to make sure I am using the latest Devise gem) and restarted the server I now see the db queries in my logfile and it works (magically).

Hope that helps.

Btw, not sure if this will help you...but these are the routes in my `Routes.rb`

```
 devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register", 
                                      :sign_in => "login", 
                                      :sign_out => "logout",
                                      :settings => "settings" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "register", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
    get "settings", :to => "devise/registrations#edit"
    get "logout",   :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"

  end
```

Comment: Thanks marcamillion.  This will be helpful when I start a new app and use the gem again.  I got so fed up initially that I just went and built this from scratch instead.  I am not sure if I tried bundle update so not sure if that would've fixed my problem.  I am glad I am not the only person with the problem though :)

Comment: Had the same issue and this fixed it.  Thanks!  Bundle update didn't change anything for me, so I think a server restart was all I needed.  The strange thing is that I was able to register a new user just fine

Comment: I guess it's appropriate to teach oneself to restart the server every once and then... it's not the first time I've gotten issues because I hadn't restarted the server after doing something that apparently required that.

Comment: `bundle update` doesn't work for me. I replaced my `devise_for :users, controllers: {...}` to `devise_for :users, path_names: {...}` and it helped me.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue when I had both

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

and

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
```

enabled simultaneously in config/initializers/devise.rb.

Upon removing the duplicate setting, authentication was successful.

Comment: I had the same problem only it had no authentication_keys in my devise.rb

Answer (score 6):

When I ran across this problem I went back through my Devise config file in

> config/initializers/devise.rb

I then found the part that I remembered I had changed to :username

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

I changed this back to `:email`. That ended up making it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the **attr_accessor** messes up with **attr_accessible**. Do you really need to have an attr_accessor?, if not simply remove it.

Try it and please let me know how it goes.

Best regards

ED

Comment: This turned out to be a mysql issue.  But in any regards, you need to add attr_accessor for :password as that is not saved to the database for security reasons

Comment: User model did not work out of the box, I had to add attr_accessor for :email in order to get rid of the error, otherwise it was always complaining about user already in db while it was not. This put me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

The username and password could both be case sensitive. Have you checked how the username is stored in your table to make sure you are entering it correctly?

In my experience when it tells you the email/password is incorrect, you can get distracted with lots of complicated ideas, but it ends up being the email or password was incorrect. It sounds like you have tried various times with resetting the password, so it makes me wonder about the username. Are you sure the right field is set up in devise as the username (ie. it could be email or a username)?

Comment: yup, i checked multiple times.  I am baffled.  I am just going to reinstall it again.

Comment: i tried uninstalling and reinstalling it again and it still doesn't work.  Wondering if it's just a bug but nobody else seems to have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

and

config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

simultaneously set in config/initializers/devise.rb will cause this error.