# Devise/Rails login not working - "invalid email or password"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm having issues with Devise. I'm trying to set up an authentication scheme in Rails and I'm getting an "invalid email or password" response when I try to sign in. This is right after creating a user, logging in, logging out, and then trying to log in again. I'm totally sure that the email/password match, so that's not the issue. I'm using Devise 4.4.3 and Rails 5.2.0. Help a guy out, please!

Users controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!

      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          flash[:notice] = "You've successfully signed up!"
        else
          flash[:alert] = "There was a problem signing up."
          redirect_to '/signup'
        end
      end

    private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
    end
```

Sessions controller:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!

      def create
        @user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        if @user
          flash[:notice] = "You've signed in."
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
          redirect_to "/"
        else
          flash[:alert] = "There was a problem signing in. Please try again."
          redirect_to signin_path
        end
      end
    end
```

User model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :posts
      has_many :projects
      attr_accessor :password
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
      before_save :encrypt_password

      def encrypt_password
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)
      end

      def self.authenticate(email, password)
        user = User.find_by "email = ?", email
        if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
          user
        else
          nil
        end
      end
    end


    <h2>Log in</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </div>
      <% end -%>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      root :to => 'homes#index'

      resources :posts
      resources :projects
      resources :users
    end
```

New session view:

```
    <h2>Log in</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </div>
      <% end -%>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Happy to provide more if needed. I'm still somewhat new to development so pardon me if it's a very obvious answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457704/ror-devise-sign-in-always-returns-invalid-email-password

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about the full stack trace? Pardon my ignorance. Also, I actually saw that question and looked through it but I didn't find a solution that worked in my case. Not a duplicate, I promise!

Comment: In your terminal, when the error occurs there is a stack trace.  here is a video that explains more: https://gorails.com/episodes/debugging-how-to-interpret-a-stacktrace

Comment: Just looking at that custom code, this could potentially be caused by so many different things... I would suggest tracking down the cause yourself - which can probably be summarised in a few lines of code, not 100!

Comment: Start by checking the `params` that are passed through. (For example, maybe it's actually `params[:user][:email]` instead of `params[:email]`??) If that's as expected, double check that the user exists, and has the same email. If things still seem fine, check whether the `BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)` matches.

Comment: Nowhere in your code does the text `"invalid email or password"` actually appear, so I can't even see which branch of the logic is failing; I can only speculate.

Comment: @TomLord That might be an error bubbling up from Devise itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the user model try this

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```